# trying to have a draggable item (jQuery) update a form element, with inconsistent results

Tags: jquery, callback, draggable

http://www.por7al.com/drag_test.html

Here is a simple demo, it is a simple jQuery draggable item, that uses the drag callback to update a form element with the absolute position of the draggable item.

Works OK, but when you make subtle movements, back and forth between grid snaps, sometimes the form element doesn't update, at least in Chrome and Safari on a Mac.

I could probably insert a stop callback, but I need it to update accurately as you drag, any ideas?

relevant codes:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    axis: "y" ,
    grid: [5,5],

    drag: function(event, ui) {
    var t=$('#draggable').offset().top;

    $('#fm').val(t);
         }
    });
```

});

To recreate the error, drag slowly back and forth between grid snaps and watch the form element. The draggable div is confined to the y-axis. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Does it help at all if you use `ui.position.top` instead of re-selecting the item.

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    grid: [5, 5],

    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var t = ui.position.top;

        $('#fm').val(t);
    }
});
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. It looks like I am going to have to rewrite some code, though. I am calling another function within the callback that is dependent on the value of t, so I will try and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Great...i have a feeling that by re-selecting the div with $('#daggable') was taking a bit longer than simply using the ui.position object that has already been calculated. Cheers